# I have a search results page but I don't know how to mix php and html!? How?

Tags: php, html, search

I have a search results page and I want to display it in tables. how do I do so? I am completely unsure of how to mix php together with html.

My code is:

```
<?php
if(strlen(trim($_POST['search'])) > 0) {

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

mysql_connect ("", "", "");
mysql_select_db ("");
if (!empty($_POST["search_string"])) 
{ 

}  

$query = "SELECT name,location,msg FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND 
location      LIKE '%$searchterm%'";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
if ($result) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
<center>
<table height="20" width="990" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>

<table height="20" width="215" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="lucidagrande" size="4" color="#045FB4">$row[0]</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
<td>

<table height="20" width="775" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="lucidagrande" size="4" color="black">$row[1]</font>
<td align="right">
<font face="lucidagrande" size="2" color="red">See More...</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
}
}
}
?>
```

Thanks!

James

Comment: I suggest starting with http://us.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one option:

```
<?php
if(strlen(trim($_POST['search'])) > 0) {

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

mysql_connect ("", "", "");
mysql_select_db ("");
if (!empty($_POST["search_string"])) 
{ 

}  

$query = "SELECT name,location,msg FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND 
location      LIKE '%$searchterm%'";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
if ($result) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) { ?>
<center>
<table height="20" width="990" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>

<table height="20" width="215" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="lucidagrande" size="4" color="#045FB4"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
<td>

<table height="20" width="775" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="lucidagrande" size="4" color="black"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></font>
<td align="right">
<font face="lucidagrande" size="2" color="red">See More...</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: there will always be someone to help :)

Comment: thanks but what do i do with the other part of the php code which links to the databse? where do i put that?

Comment: Just replace everything from the while loop down to the first curly brace :)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ',' or ';' in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage21/fo/ur/wa/fourwaysdp.co.uk/public_html/searchresults.php on line 131


Is the error i get and the row is

<table height="20" width="215" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

I dont get it!?! lol

Comment: I've updated my post to include the original script, all of it, changed to how you want it to work - try that :)

Comment: Thanks for the help ashley!

I got one more error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage21/fo/ur/wa/fourwaysdp.co.uk/public_html/searchresults.php on line 149

and the line just says </html>

why is it wrong to put this at the end of a page containing html?

Comment: Sorry, me being a pleb - check my post again and try that :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP parsing is based on the existence of two tags:

```
<?php
?>
```

Anything inside the PHP "xml" tags is to be PHP code. Anything outside is to be normal HTML. So:

```
<p><?php echo 'Hello, world!'; ?></p>
```

Means to output the `<p></p>` normally, but let the PHp parser handle the `echo 'Hello, world!';`

So, changes are that after your `while(...){` statement you want a `?>` (to end PHP code and begin outputting the `<center>` tag and tables.) Then, towards the bottom, you'll need a `<?php` before the braces (`}`).

Finally, every time you see a variable like `$row[0]` you'll need to surround it with php tags. either of these is acceptable:

```
<?=$row[0];?>
<?php echo $row[0]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to end the PHP before you can start the HTML, and vice versa.

```
<?php
// PHP goes here
?>
<!-- HTML goes here -->
<?php
// More PHP here
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the php tags where php code is e.g.

```
<font face="lucidagrande" size="4" color="black"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></font>
```